# How to maintain multi client customization changes with one code base in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, customization

In my spring boot application i want to maintain multi client customization changes with same code base. i don't want to create separate branch for different different clients.

Current structure of my project :-

```
  src
   main
    java
     com.exa.app.controller
     com.exa.app.service
     com.exa.app.dao
```

1. So now if one client need some more new APIs then how will i create ? , that new code should not go in other clients builds.
2. Suppose i have one add user rest API and service and DAO function to add new user this is common for all clients but one clients wants some new validation and call another additional function before saving user. so how we can handle this case as its just customization for particular one client ?

Any suggestions ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is highly opinionated but as a start: Either implement "feature toggles" where you have some kind of flag to activate/deactivate features and everyone gets the same artifact in the end or factor the common parts into one Maven module and make specific Maven artifacts for every customer (kind of like an inheritance hierarchy where there is a "abstract" common part and "concrete" parts for every customer).

Comment: @Smutje Thanks for the reply.. i was searching the same solution like if somehow i can be able to design something parent child hierarchy. i went through maven multi module architecture but not got it much

Comment: It would be a problem shipping code aimed to other clients but that won't be accessible? I was thinking of using profiles for this problem. For example, having a `Validator` interface with different implementations for each client, marked with a `@Profile('clientX')` annotation.

Comment: You would have 1 JAR artifact containing the common code and N (N=number of clients) WAR artifacts containing the controllers for each specific client.

Comment: @Smutje  you are referring the maven multi module structure correct ? you mean i need to create one parent project it will contain all common code and client based N child projects which will contain client related customization code correct me if am wrong ?

Comment: A "parent" project is just conceptually a parent, but from a technical point of view it is just one module beside others.

Comment: @Smutje  yes sure i got this concept, but you suggest in child module i will have different controller based on client requirements, yesterday for testing purpose i implemented one test parent child hierarchy so i was just able to access only one module's controller which had main function annotated with '@SpringBootApplication' , others module controller i was not able to access. so in parent child structure does it have only one main class OR  we can create main class for all modules ?

Comment: Depends on if you want to have different artifacts for every client or one artifact for all clients.

Comment: @LuisIñesta   In profile annotation can we pass profile name dynamically on build time ?